# QuickTime 10.1 stops responding

Tags: macos, quicktime

Quicktime (10.1) keeps quitting when I try to launch an .avi file on OS X Lion. I have removed the codecs I had installed (I used cleanmymac to completely remove leftovers) I also deleted Quicktime and re-installed it from my Lion recovery disk and the application still gives me an error report when I try to open a .avi file. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Also, the avi files are working fine on quicklook.

Here is the log file:
[image: QT Log]

Comment: Any knows a place where i should post this that might give me an answer?

Comment: Try installing Quicktime Player X, or Quicktime Player 7. QT Player 7 is [available on the Apple website for free](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/) and QT Player X should be on your system. Take a look at [the Apple website](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/)

Comment: I have installed Quicktime player X already thats the one i got problem with.

Comment: I have had problems opening certain avi files with QuickTime. Is it just one file that theres a problem with?

Comment: There are some that work but most files won't open. After trying to reinstall quicktimeX from recovery i don't get the error but files still don't play.

Comment: Do you have to use QuickTime? Have you tried Movist, NicePlayer, MPlayerX?

Comment: Yes I now use MPlayerX for .avi. This is a bit old question.